# Kotlin, Android - Position of Viewpager parent (which is a RecyclerView) - Click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I got a fragment with a recyclerView, and the item of it it's a cardview that contain a viewpager (which represents a gallery).

I'm trying to figured out how I can know the position of the viewpager and recyclerview as well, when I touch the respective element of viewpager.

[image]

**Click of the image:**

```
image.setOnClickListener{
      val intent_full = Intent(context, FullscreenActivity::class.java)
      intent_full.putExtra("galeria", imagesUri!![position])
      intent_full.putExtra("positionGallery", position)
      auxPositionGallery = position
      Log.d("positionGallery", position.toString())
      context.startActivity(intent_full)
}
```

´
**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
  class CartaoTipologiaAdapter(private val context: Context, private val 
  cartoesTipologiaModelArrayList: ArrayList<WoundsClass>)
  : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartaoTipologiaAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val adapter = ViewPageAdapter(context)

        /**ViewPager*/
        val vp : ViewPager = holder.viewPager
        holder.viewPager.adapter = adapter
        holder.viewPager.currentItem = imagesUri!!.size

        /**PageIndicatorView*/
        holder.pageIndicatorView.setViewPager(vp)
        holder.pageIndicatorView.count = imagesUri!!.size
        holder.pageIndicatorView.selection = imagesUri!!.size
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of is, in onBindViewHolder of the RecyclerViewAdapter, you can send the position of the current RecyclerView's position to your ViewPagerAdapter, or wherever you can retrieve this data later when onClick occurs on your ImageView. Attaching a View tag is also an option. You can attach the position in the RecyclerView as a View tag and whenever you click an image, you can call view.getTag() or so.